# Capturar e-mail de páginas

Tags: php

Eu tenho um sistema de e-mails com o endereço:

```
 http://www.site.com.br/123/123/123.php?p=1&codelist=1
```

que vai até:

```
 http://www.site.com.br/123/123/123.php?p=460&codelist=1
```

(p=1 é a página)

Ou seja, 460 páginas. Neste sistema eu tenho todos os dados dos meus clientes.

Eu preciso de um código que acesse essas 460 urls e capture apenas o e-mail listadas no site e ignore outros dados. Enfim, apenas o e-mail e salve em um TXT.

Alguém consegue me ajudar? Não tenho ideia de como fazer.

Comment: _" Neste sistema eu tenho todos os dados dos meus clientes"_ - como estás a gerar o conteúdo dessas páginas? não podes ir simplesmente à base de dados?

Comment: Marcelo, esses dados ficam em um banco de dados ou impressos diretamente no html? Consegue mandar um exemplo de como esses valores ficam registrados?

Comment: @Sergio, é um sistema antigo e mal feito... ele apresenta em html na propria pagina em tabelas... só que são muitos dados e eu preciso no momento apenas dos e-mails para entrar em contato.

Comment: @Csorgo, são listados assim: <tr><td  bgcolor=#ECEDE8>21/11/2009<br>08:05:38</td><tr><td  bgcolor=#ECEDE8><font size=1 class="slk">Status<br>Inativo<br><a href="gerenciar_usuarios.asp?p=1&codativacao=116034&codlist=30"  style="font-family:Trebuchet MS,tahoma,arial,verdana; font-size:12px; color: #ffffff; text-decoration:none; background: #109809;">&nbsp;Ativar Cadastro&nbsp;</u></a></td><td  bgcolor=#ECEDE8><font class="slk"></td><td  bgcolor=#ECEDE8><font class="slk">
email@email.com.br</td>

Comment: cada página com um email?

Comment: Recomendo que edite sua pergunta e forneça mais algumas informações, exemplo: Como esses dados estão guardados? Isso ajuda a entender melhor seu problema e também a organizar melhor o site para não ficar tudo jogado aqui nos comentários.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**exemplo - ideone - capturar email**](https://ideone.com/DY4XGL)

```
$url="http://www.site.com.br/123/123/123.php?p=1&codelist=1";
$text=file_get_contents($url);

$res = preg_match_all(
"/[a-z0-9]+[_a-z0-9\.-]*[a-z0-9]+@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})/i",
$text,
$matches
);

//caso haja somente um email
$email = reset($matches[0])."\n";
file_put_contents('emails.txt', $email, FILE_APPEND);
// fim caso haja um email

/* caso haja mais de um email
foreach($matches[0] as $email){
    file_put_contents('emails.txt', $email."\n", FILE_APPEND);
}
*/
```

[file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-get-contents.php)  - Lê todo o conteúdo de um arquivo para uma string

A função `preg_match_all()` retornará um número inteiro com a quantidade de ocorrências encontradas pela expressão regular.

`reset()` retrocede o ponteiro interno de array para o primeiro elemento e retorna o valor do primeiro elemento do array.

`file_put_contents` escreve uma string em um arquivo, caso este arquivo ainda não exista ele cria o arquivo.

`FILE_APPEND` acrescenta um valor em um arquivo já criado.

> O script acima é para uma página, mas nada impede de fazer um loop variando o valor de `p` em `$url`

```
for ($x = 1; $x <= 460; $x++) {
   $url="http://www.site.com.br/123/123/123.php?p=".$x."&codelist=1";
   $text=file_get_contents($url);

   $res = preg_match_all(
"/[a-z0-9]+[_a-z0-9\.-]*[a-z0-9]+@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})/i",
  $text,
  $matches
  );

  //caso haja somente um email
  $email = reset($matches[0])."\n";
  file_put_contents('emails.txt', $email, FILE_APPEND);
  // fim caso haja um email
}
```

Comment: Ok, adiantou bastante para o que eu preciso. Porém, desculpe a falta de conhecimento, como são 460 páginas, como eu deveria colocar para pegar de todas as página? e não ter que ficar mudando o p=1 p=2 etc?

Comment: @Marcelo editei a resposta. Veja no final no loop for.

Comment: Leo, quando eu uso esse código: ele não funciona, entretanto, quando eu faço por url sem utilizar o FOR ele funciona normalmente. Tem ideia do que pode ser? Não tem nada errado? `<?php

for ($x = 1; $x <= 3; $x++) {
   $url="http://www.site.com.br/123/123/123.php?p=".$x."&codelist=1"; //eu fiz a alteração da url
$text=file_get_contents($url);

$res = preg_match_all(
"/[a-z0-9]+[_a-z0-9\.-]*[a-z0-9]+@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})/i",
$text,
$matches
);




foreach($matches[0] as $email){
    file_put_contents('emails.txt', $email."\n", FILE_APPEND);
}

}


?>`

Comment: Esse seu código está com uma codificação extranha. Sugiro copiar o meu colar em um editor de texto puro (bloco de notas) salvar e depois copiar e colar na sua aplicação.

Comment: Leo, acabe ide fazer exatamente isso e o arquivo emails.txt continua em branco. Quando eu coloco a sua primeira resposta, funciona.

Comment: Na verdade vc só tem uma pagina e não 460. Mas o estranho que uma a uma funciona e no loop for não. No meu teste fiz com 3 paginas mesmo exem1.htm exem2.htm e exem3.htm sem parametros na url.

Comment: Precisaríamos ver isso em chat mas não está abrindo o chat para nós

Comment: essa pagina http://www.site.com.br/123/123/123.php gostaria de ver o código dela

Comment: Fiz um teste para abrir uma pagina com vários parâmetros igualzinho a sua e funcionou corretamente.  $url="http://........../sos/exem.php?p=".$x."&codelist=1";

Comment: Leo, o erro era meu! Estava funcionando sim! Muito obrigado pela ajuda!